# Find ranges of a larger range not covered by a list of subranges

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Apologies for the perhaps confusing title.

Suppose you have a range (0,10000) and a list of smaller sub-ranges that may overlap [(20,3460),(200,3000),(2800,8704)] and you want to return the ranges of the original range NOT covered by the sub-ranges, in this case [(0, 19), (8705, 10000)]

I am trying to figure out how to do this efficiently to work with larger ranges and more numerous sub-ranges. I thought about using itertools.chain to create a single range from the list of sub-ranges to take care of overlaps and then somehow using that range to slice the larger range, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

If it helps to know the purpose, I am trying to create a list of coding sequences that are wholly or partially in the unaligned regions of a genomic comparison given the ranges of the aligned regions and ranges of the coding sequences. If the coding sequence is only partially aligned, I want to be able to return the ranges that are unaligned.

Comment: Shouldn't answer for your example be `[(0, 19), (8705, 10000)]`? Because `(200,3000)` lies in `(20,3460)` and `(2800,8704)` intersect with `(20,3460)`, so they become `(20,8704)`?

Comment: You're correct, edited.

Comment: BEDOPS is a fast genomic set operation toolkit. https://github.com/bedops/bedops and `bedops --merge` piped to `bedops --difference`. No need to use Python to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That's nice but I'm running Windows and interested in keeping this whole process in python for my current purposes.

Comment: Or look into pyranges (https://github.com/pyranges/pyranges)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[intspan](https://intspan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be used to get the complement of the sub ranges.

```
from intspan import intspan

start, end = (0,10000)

subs = [(20,3460),(200,3000),(2800,8704)]

span = intspan.from_ranges(subs)
comp = span.complement(low=start, high=end).ranges()

print(comp)
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 19), (8705, 10000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in the comments there's `O(NlogN)` solution

```
start_val, end_val = 0, 10_000

if len(segments) == 0:
    result = [(start_val, end_val)]
else:
    # Sort by start position of segments
    segments = sorted(segments, key=lambda x: x[0])
    merged_segments = []
    
    # Merge overlapping segments
    ind = 0
    while ind < len(segments):
        start = ind
        
        while ind + 1 < len(segments) and (segments[ind+1][0] - segments[ind][1]) <= 1:
            ind += 1
        
        if start == ind:
            merged_segments.append(segments[start])
        else:
            merged_segments.append((segments[start][0], segments[ind][1]))
        
        ind += 1

    # Build 'compliment' sequence
    result = []
    cur = start_val
    
    for (seg_start, seg_end) in merged_segments:
        if cur < seg_start:
            result.append((cur, seg_start - 1))
        cur = seg_end + 1

    if cur < end_val:
        result.append((cur, end_val))
    
print(result)
```

*Note*

Please test this code **thoroughly**!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your problem can be narrowed down to the following:

1. We have a global range, let's call it `glob_rng`.
2. We have a set of ranges we want to remove from `glob_rng`, let's call them `ranges_to_subtract`.
3. We now want to remove all ranges within `ranges_to_subtract` from `glob_rng`, such that we yield a set of ranges that's non-overlapping with any of `ranges_to_subtract`.
4. Let's call the result `ranges_res` and assign it the initial value of `ranges_res = set((<range from>, <range to>))`, where `range from` and `range to` have to replaced with actual integers.

Given this description, for each of the ranges within `ranges_to_subtract` we have to apply the range removal to the set of resulting ranges.
For each range `(xs, ys)` to subtract and for each remaining range `(xr, yr)` from the global range, there can be the following four cases:

```
1. xr < xs and yr > ys:
   xr <==================> yr
         xs <=======> ys

2. xr >= ys or yr <= xs: 
   xs <===> ys
         xr <===> yr
               xs <====> ys
3. xr >= xs and yr <= ys:
       xr <========> yr
   xs <===============> ys

4. xr >= xs and yr > ys:
      xr <==================> yr
   xs <=======> ys

5. xr < xs and yr <= ys:
   xr <==================> yr
                  xs <=======> ys
```

Note, that the case that `xr == xs and yr == ys` is handled by 3 and that the order matters.

Given these definitions, implementation should be possible, take the following as a starting point

```py
from typing import Set, Tuple


def subtract_ranges(
    glob_rng: Tuple[int, int],
    ranges_to_subtract: Set[Tuple[int, int]],
):
    ranges_res = {glob_rng}

    for xs, ys in ranges_to_subtract:
        rngs_temp = set()
        for xr, yr in ranges_res:
            if xr < xs and yr > ys:
                rngs_temp |= {(xr, xs), (ys, yr)}
            elif xr >= ys or yr <= xs:
                rngs_temp |= {(xr, yr)}
            elif xr >= xs and yr > ys:
                rngs_temp |= {(ys, yr)}
            elif xr < xs and yr <= ys:
                rngs_temp |= {(xr, xs)}
            elif xr >= xs and yr <= ys:
                rngs_temp = set()

        ranges_res = rngs_temp
    return ranges_res


assert {(10, 50), (90, 100)} == subtract_ranges(
    glob_rng=(0, 100),
    ranges_to_subtract={
        (0, 10),
        (50, 60),
        (50, 60),
        (55, 60),
        (50, 55),
        (52, 55),
        (60, 90),
    },
)
```